# Rails Assets Precompile Failed Assertion `tag <= GUMBO_TAG_LAST' failed

Tags: c, ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

Can anyone please figure out this issue, I can't found the solution since last night.

I tried upgrade my app from ruby `2.3.x` to ruby `2.6.x`, and rails from `4.2.x` to rails `5.2.x`,
my app is running well on my mac, including assets precompile.

Then migrated from an old server to a new staging server (gcp) with new ubuntu os `20.04.2 LTS`

I got this error when deploy and to do run manually :

```
user@app-focal:/var/www/html/app/releases/20211223175449$ RAILS_ENV=staging ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.6.8@app do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
I, [2021-12-24T00:56:12.981740 #108442]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/html/app/releases/20211223175449/public/assets/tinymce-5c5b8b58ae365223e6d3f58192e4d1ca79f4b920f237f3d3a985d6221f658c25.js.gz
ruby /var/www/html/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rake assets:precompile: tag.c:181: gumbo_normalized_tagname: Assertion `tag <= GUMBO_TAG_LAST' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Stack :

- rvm 1.29.12
- bundler 2.3.0
- ruby 2.6.8
- rails 5.2.6
- nodejs 14.16.0 / 16.13.1 / 17.3.0

Comment: We'd need to see the _code_ for declaration/initialization/assignment of `tag`. Also, what is the value of `GUMBO_TAG_LAST` for _both_ old and new versions of the requisite `.h` file in which it is defined? (e.g.) in the old version, it could be 20 but in the new version it could be 10 and `tag` could be 15 in both cases. Or, although less likely, it could be `tag` that has different values rev-to-rev. You could add `printf` to show the values above the `assert` and try both versions again

Comment: @CraigEstey I got it, I use gem `nokogiri`, and it's also upgraded, so I need downgrade it, and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't solution but I try make short-term solution.

When you try to upgrade your rails app, you need a plan and analyze your current app in all aspect.

My issue is common. I try to bundle update and some gem on my Gemfile didn't set the version, so some gems was upgraded including `nokigiri`. My app is too old, especially with assets. my assets can't precompile with new version of `nokogiri`, so I just downgraded it and the error was gone.

I will find the issue then, why in my local machine (mac) is running well but not on the server.